# How can I filter foreign key field in django?

Tags: django, orm

```
class Group(models.Model):
    pass

class User(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    created_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

If this model exist, how can I get user filtered by post about specific date in specific group?

ex) user who post last week in group A

_group => specific group

```
_group.user_set.filter(posts__created_time__gt=from_date, posts__created_time__lt=to_date)
```

I use this code, but I can't get any user that has posts in specific date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you just need to add a relation between `User` and `Post`. Also you don't need to overwrite existing django user, you cant just inherit fields for it and add your own.:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Group(models.Model):
    pass

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='posts')
    created_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now you can easily do your query in such a way:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(posts__created_published__range=[from_date, to_date])
```

Comment: This code is same empty result. If use without "posts__created_published__range=[from_date, to_date]", I can get whole data. I don't know why I can't get specific dates.

Comment: @egaoneko, are you sure that there are objects in a given range?

Comment: That's my mistake, I have a mistake that switch from_date, to_date. Thank you!

Comment: And then, I got user data. But I don't know how can I get posts which post specific date? User's posts field has posts which post whole dates.

Comment: @egaoneko, If I understand you right you can just do `Post.objects.filter(created_time__range=[from_date, to_date])`

Comment: I need specific group's user posts that posts between specific date.

Comment: @egaoneko, you can chain filters as many times as you need: `UserProfile.objects.filter(groups=group).filter(posts__created_published__range=[from_date, to_date])`

Comment: It has same result. I think it caused by user model. It just show user model posts field..

Comment: @egaoneko, I think I've misunderstood you again. Then you just need to add one more `ForeignKey` to your `Post` model : `group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='group_posts')` and query like this `Post.objects.filter(group=group).filter(group__userprofile_set=user)`

Comment: Thank you for your helping!

Comment: Yes, but I try to combine, both of them like (user, posts). I need both of them  because I want to make such as "last week hottest user, posts written by user last week". I use django rest framework, so I search how can I return multiple results for (user, posts).

Answer (score 0):

if you want user, you should start the query with user model:

```
User.objects.filter(
    groups__in=[_group], 
    posts__created_time__gt=from_date, 
    posts__created_time__lt=to_date
)
```

Comment: This code is same empty result, too. If use "User.objects.filter(groups__in=[_group])", I can get whole data. I don't know why I can't get specific dates.

Comment: That's my mistake, I have a mistake that switch from_date, to_date. Thank you!

Comment: I got it. Can I ask one question? I got user data. But I don't know how can I get posts which post specific date? User's posts field has posts which post whole dates.